# apply lamba to df based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

If I can make up a df with some random data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 24,3
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature1','Temperature2','Value'], index=tidx)
```

How could I use the lamba function to add `5000` to each row to the columns Temperature1 & Temperature2 only if the df index hour is less than 6?

If I use

```
for hour in df.index.hour:
    if hour < 6:# and name contains 'Temperature'
        df = df.apply(lambda x: x + 5000)
```

The above code isnt correct it adds 5000 to all rows in the df. Any tips greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

You can do with `loc`:

```
# get the temperature columns
temp_cols = [x for x in df.columns if 'Temperature' in x]

# update with loc access
df.loc[df.index.hour<6, temp_cols] += 5000
```

Output:

```
                     Temperature1  Temperature2     Value
2019-01-01 00:00:00   5000.180270   5000.019475  0.463219
2019-01-01 01:00:00   5000.724934   5000.420204  0.485427
2019-01-01 02:00:00   5000.012781   5000.487372  0.941807
2019-01-01 03:00:00   5000.850795   5000.729964  0.108736
2019-01-01 04:00:00   5000.893904   5000.857154  0.165087
2019-01-01 05:00:00   5000.632334   5000.020484  0.116737
2019-01-01 06:00:00      0.316367      0.157912  0.758980
2019-01-01 07:00:00      0.818275      0.344624  0.318799
2019-01-01 08:00:00      0.111661      0.083953  0.712726
2019-01-01 09:00:00      0.599543      0.055674  0.479797
2019-01-01 10:00:00      0.401676      0.847979  0.717849
2019-01-01 11:00:00      0.602064      0.552384  0.949102
2019-01-01 12:00:00      0.986673      0.338054  0.239875
2019-01-01 13:00:00      0.796436      0.063686  0.364616
2019-01-01 14:00:00      0.070023      0.319368  0.070383
2019-01-01 15:00:00      0.290264      0.790101  0.905400
2019-01-01 16:00:00      0.792621      0.561819  0.616018
2019-01-01 17:00:00      0.361484      0.168817  0.436241
2019-01-01 18:00:00      0.732825      0.062888  0.020733
2019-01-01 19:00:00      0.770548      0.299952  0.701164
2019-01-01 20:00:00      0.734668      0.932905  0.400328
2019-01-01 21:00:00      0.358438      0.806567  0.764491
2019-01-01 22:00:00      0.652615      0.810967  0.642215
2019-01-01 23:00:00      0.957444      0.333874  0.738253
```

Comment: Thanks @Quang for the answer

Comment: ```df.index.hour``` will not work because it is a range index, you can try the following:

```df["hour"] = df.reset_index()["index"].dt.hour```

Comment: @cpernul from OP's sample, it's datetime index.

Comment: @QuangHoang, If I want to change the entire value of `temp_cols` if the hour is 6AM. would you have a tip to do that? This doesnt work, for example if hour == 6, `df.loc[df.index.hour==6, temp_cols] == 68`. No error it just doesnt change anything

Comment: I’m surprised that it didn’t work. Did you get any errors/warning running that code?

Comment: Actually I figured it out :) This works `df.loc[df.index.hour==6, temp_cols]= 68`

Answer (score 1):

Boolean select contains Temperature

```
m=df.columns.str.contains('Temperature')
m
```

Select rows with hour<6 and Update by;

```
df.loc[df.index.hour<6, m] += 5000
df
```